# Django Form | Group Model | MultiSelect | getting only single value from the form by using MultiSelect widget

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to get input from the user in a template, I am showing list of Groups in template available from the Group model in Django Auth Models and expecting multiple values.
But it is only returning single value even selecting multiple options

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    the_choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(),
                                                 required=False, 
                                                 widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        exclude = ['name', 'permissions']

    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import MyForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View

class see(View):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get(self, request):
        context ={}
        context['form']= MyForm()
        return render(request, "home.html", context)
    
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.POST.get('the_choices'))

        return HttpResponse('Great!')
```

Template - Input Form Image

[image]

Output in Console

[image]

kindly refer to image 2, I expect 1 and 2 (group name preferred) in console but its returning only 2.

Comment: Exactly what part is printing the choices? Where in your view do you print?

Comment: Can you please show your views.py code

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: added views.py code for reference @rahul.m

Comment: Sure! Actually This was my first time asking question in stackoverflow @willem-van-onsem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you access `request.POST.get('key')` (or `request.POST['key']`), you only get the *last* value associated with that key.

You access all values with the [**`.getlist(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

```
print(request.POST.getlist('the_choices'))
```

But normally you process data with the form itself, so:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    print(form.cleaned_data['the_choices'])
```

This will also clean the data and return model objects, not their primary keys.

Comment: Can we add a search bar for that choices field, like just search and select?

Answer (score 1):

use **getlist**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist

try this

```
the_choices = request.POST.getlist('the_choices')
```

Comment: Can we add a search bar for that choices field, like just search and select?

Comment: @GautamDhiman you can use https://select2.org/

Comment: I am not allowed to use third party package!